# SSRS Report Viewer 2016 printig on Chrome do not work

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services, report-viewer2016

I am trying to implement SSRS Report Viewer 2016 control on my Webpage
I did install package `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms -Pre` it is now on version 140.1.291.2731477-rc
When I open page whit report-viewer it looks all right .
When I try to print on chrome 
I get Print dialog for Page orientation and page size.
After click on print, nothing happend.
On chrome developer tools in console screen get message:

```
Resource interpreted as Document : 
Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=14.0.1.291&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.Web…
but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: http://localhost:54071/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession
```

[image: Chrom Console]

If I try to print in EDGE i get print screen dialog without problems.¸(PDF get oppened)

If I try on Firefox I get PDF opened inside Dialog Window.

Does printing in chrome requierd ADOBE extension.
I do open PDF-s inside chrome whitout problems.

Can this issue be caused becouse report viewer control rendering report hosted  on SSRS2012 services. (Control is 2016 ver but it render remotely hosted SSRS2012 reports).

Comment: Chrome has it's own embedded pdf viewer but sometimes things are not working with print dialogue. There is an adobe plugin for chrome, give it a try to see if works in your case.

Comment: @niktrs same behavior with adobe extension inside chrome. Again no print dialog same message in console